# Why does Virtualenv keep using the global python binary?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have set up a python virtualenv but it is not using the virtual python binary.

```
root@localhost# pwd
/root/project
root@localhost# ls
env  src
root@localhost# source env/bin/activate
(env)root@localhost# which python
/usr/bin/python
(env)root@localhost# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

I have no idea why it is doing this.

EDIT:

I do have the interpreter

```
(env)root@localhost# pwd
/root/project/env/bin
(env)root@localhost# ls
activate       activate_this.py  pip     python
activate.csh   easy_install      pip3    python3
activate.fish  easy_install-3.4  pip3.4  python3.4
```

EDIT 2:
I should probably mention I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Cloud 9. It should work to my knowledge.

EDIT 3:

Here is my path

```
root@localhost# echo $PATH
/root/env/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

I know what happened. I have since moved the env directory since its creation. The addition to $PATH is "outdated". Bottom line, don't move the virtualenv directory.

Comment: Can you show the output that you get when setting up the `virtualenv`? Do you have a python interpreter in `env/bin/`?

Comment: Yes, I do have the interpreter, see edit

Comment: Did you happen to move or rename the env after you created it? See http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#making-environments-relocatable

Comment: I did. That is the problem. $PATH is no longer looking in the right directory since I moved `env`. I guess I shouldn't have moved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably renamed/moved it – virtualenv's are not relocatable by default. See

http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#making-environments-relocatable

for more information.